# EF Core migration to Postgres database "relation" already exists

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I have a situation where the database and tables were already created before I brought in EF migrations, which is added to the program.cs like so:

```
var app = builder.Build();
await app.MigrateDatabase();
```

I have these two migrations:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pem8b.png)

To try to tell EF that these migrations were already ran so that it doesn't attempt to create a table that already exists, the migration table was created and two rows were inserted:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public."__EFMigrationsHistory"
(
    migration_id character varying(150) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    product_version character varying(32) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT pk___ef_migrations_history PRIMARY KEY (migration_id)
)

TABLESPACE pg_default;

ALTER TABLE IF EXISTS public."__EFMigrationsHistory"
    OWNER to postgres;
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qrKar.png)

But I'm still encountering this error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dMZEV.png)

I know that I should've let EF migrations create the db since the start but that's besides the point.

It seems like EF cannot find this table/db rows for some reason? Any suggestions would be appreciated.

If it matters, this code is pushed to a Linux machine.

I created the migration table manually and added the two "migrated" rows but I'm still getting this error.